# Trying to port windows build system to linux

Tags: c++, linux, sublimetext3, build-system, sublime-build

This build system is for competitive coding in c++ on sublime text in 3 column view

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++17", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "./${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
"selector":"source.cpp"
}
```

**edits made for the port**

```
{
"cmd": ["g++","-std=c++17", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}", "&&" , "./${file_base_name}<inputf.in>outputf.in"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
"selector":"source.cpp"
}
```

**errors**

```
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['g++', '-std=c++17', '/home/xxx/Documents/CP/file.cpp', '-o', 'file', '&&', './file<inputf.in>outputf.in']]
[dir: /home/xxx/Documents/CP]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl]
```

**edits made for the port v2**

```
{ 
"cmd": ["g++ -std=c++17 ${file} -o ${file_base_name}"," && ", "./${file_base_name}<inputf.in>outputf.in"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
}
```

**using the new v2 build system the no input file issue is resolved and the file is complied but still there is no output in the outputf.in file**

using just the command in terminal

`g++ -std=c++17 file.cpp -o file && ./file<inputf.in>outputf.in`

produces output in the outputf.in file

Comment: Looks like the file `/home/xxx/Documents/CP/file.cpp` does not exist.

Comment: it does checked for that issue first

Comment: Did you open a command line and validate the command works there?

Comment: ```g++ -std=c++17 file.cpp -o file.o``` and ```./file.o <inputf.in>outputf.in``` works fine

Comment: Why in the world is your final executable given a `.o` extension? That extension should be reserved for the intermediate object files, which they have by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
"cmd": ["g++ -std=c++17 ${file} -o ${file_base_name} && ./${file_base_name}<inputf.in>outputf.in"]
```

this build command seems to do the trick for me it works perfectly fine for me, i dont know why and how this works but it does.

this build file was inspired form a blog post at

https://blog.codingblocks.com/2019/setting-up-a-c-competitive-programming-environment/